# FFmpeg output buffer/delay reduction

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I would like to get frames as they become available from FFmpeg.
I tried different codecs and options both for video and audio conversion but here is a simple example:
ffmpeg -i rtmp://input -vn -c:a libmp3lame -f mp3 -reservoir 0 http://127.0.0.1:7885
and there is also an http server on the localhost that gets the data and outputs timings between successive chunks.
It seems it gets it in batches (which happens when transcode_step -> reap_filters -> do_video_out/do_audio_out in ffmpeg.c is called) and there are 0.5-1.5 second pauses in between.
Different options like -maxrate, -bufsize, -g, -muxdelay, -tune zerolatency didn't seem to do any difference.
**EDIT**
It seems that setting -re (Read input at native frame rate) removes the issue, but is says it 'Should not be used with actual grab devices or live input streams (where it can cause packet loss).'.

Comment: Did you try `-flush_packets 1`?

Comment: @aergistal, Thanks, I just tried and there was no difference